# Assign Variable(True/False) to many conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am doing Grok Learning Course, and have come across a problem. Sorry if I have done anything badly; not a professional at coding:

I am trying to make a variable that will be True/False depending on many conditions:

So,

```
    x = True  if  y > 2 , g < 4 , n != 3
```

I have tried different ways to do this like:

Assigning variable to each of my conditions:

```
    if y > 2:
       ytrue = True
```

etc..
However, I want to find a better way of doing it than that, which is long and tedious. 
Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
x = y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3
```

which evaluates to `True` if all three conditions hold and `False` otherwise.

As you are new to programming, here's how you read it.

First you evaluate the right hand side which is

```
y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3
```

This is evaluated left to right. First it evaluates `y > 2` which will either be `True` or `False`. If `False` the whole right hand side is `False` and `False` will be assigned to `x`. Otherwise it keeps on evaluating all of the other sub-expressions on the right hand side until one of them is `False` or until you've found every one to be `True`, in which case the whole right hand side is `True`.

In either case, `True` or `False`, your variable `x` gets the desired value.

Comment: No worries! There are many ways to do it.... you can even use `if` statements, but it's good to get used to the `and` expressions as it is the most direct way. Python is nice and clean and expresive. Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3
```

If you have multiple expressions and if you want to do expression on a expression using and's & or's combinations its better to put it on like this

```
 x= ((y > 2 and g < 4) or n != 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operators like (>, <, !=, etc.) all end up being evaluated down to True or False by the python interpreter.

Python also has Boolean the operators and, or, not ([Read more in Section 4.2 of the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)) but you can use these in combination with the comparison operators to chain them. So your assignment becomes:

```
x =  y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary conditional operator :

```
['false','true'][y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3]
```

How it works ?

```
True == 1, False == 0
```

because booleans are a subclass of int , so `[y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3]` produce a integer value but `['false','true']` takes it as index value.

```
True gives ['false','true'][1]
And False gives ['false','true'][0]
```

Test case:

```
y=4
g=1
n=3
print(['false','true'][y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3])
```

output:

```
false
```

Test case2:

```
y=4
g=1
n=1
print(['false','true'][y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3])
```

output:

```
true
```

Now, if you want you can store the result in a variable :

```
x=['false','true'][y > 2 and g < 4 and n != 3]
```

which you wanted i think.